# GraphQL: Access type properties within @auth header

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

Say I have a GraphQL schema similar to:

```
type Posts 
  @model 
  @auth(rules: [
      {allow: groups, groups: ["Employees"], mutations: [create, update, delete, get, list]}
    ])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String
  groups: [String]!
}
```

And I want to allow only users who are listed in the Post's `groups` attribute to have those properties. I'd like to do something like:

```
 @auth(rules: [
          {allow: groups, groups: [Device.groups], mutations: [create, update, delete, get, list]}
 ]
```

Any ideas where to start? I'm relatively new to GraphQL and it's entirely possible that I'm headed completely in the wrong direction. Please help.

**EDIT**

I managed to achieve a similar result by modifying the resolver. In the case of `list`, it looks something like this:

```
    other code...
    #foreach( $postGroup in $item.groups )
        #foreach( $userGroup in $userGroups )
            #if( $postGroup == $userGroup )
                $util.qr($items.add($item))
            #end
        #end
    #end
    ...other code
```

This is of course a very inefficient way to do it (i.e. nested foreach loops), but this stems from my lack of knowledge of Apache VLT and will be resolved at some point.

**I do still wonder, however, is it possible to do this directly in the GraphQL schema?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet supported by the GraphQL transform, but this is an interesting use case that I think we should look into further. Can you please add a feature request here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues and provide your use case and suggestion for how to best implement this in a generic way. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks for your answer. Reference this link for the feature request: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/105